# I have several EF Migrations. What happens if I change the connection string and run database update?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have been updating my entities in development and that resulted in several migrations and update database commands, to a particular database.

What happens if I change the connection string (because the new database sits on a later version of SQL Server, for example) and then run the `database update` again? I have the impression that EF would detect the new database, run through all of my migrations, and produce one script and execute so that my new database has all the tables, columns, and relationships exactly as how the last migration left it. Can I just change the connection string and I'll get the new database as expected?

Many tell me that I have to create a separate deployment project for each database I want to manipulate with EF, but that seems rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are different Tables and Columns it will bomb out right away with an Exception on the mismatched column/table name, if your databases are the exact same (and at the same Migration History), it should update it.

If you have two Databases that are not on the same migration history, you can run

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration migrationName
```

And this will effectively revert a Migration, just be sure to delete the migration that was added to the solution directory. (This sometimes happens when switching between branches / databases a lot, and may save you some time)

> "Can I just change the connection string and I'll get the new database as expected?"

As long as the Migration History isn't mismatched and the Connection String is Pointing to the right place.

> "Many tell me that I have to create a separate deployment project for each database I want to manipulate with EF"

If you are using Visual Studio, you can create different publishing profiles if needed

Comment: I should have clarified that the connection string is that of an empty database without a migration history table. Even then, is that still considered a migration history mismatch?

Comment: No because it is going to update from the beginning of your Migration files, it will run them in sequence and each to it's Migration History when run